# OCR PDF image to Excel by template

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, ocr

[image]I need to convert a lot PDF tables data scans with bad quality to excel tables. The only way I see the solution is to train tesseract or some other framework on pre-generated images(all tables in PDF are the same in most cases). Is it real to have a great solution around 70-80% at home conditions and what you can advice. I will appreciate any advice other than Abby FineReader or similar solution(tested on my dataset - result is so bad and few opportunities for automation)

All tables structures need to be correct in result for further handwork.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Added a picture. Maybe you can estimate the approximate chances of recognizing such scans? Is there a way of better preprocessing image for FineReader or make template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a PDF parser for that.

Here's the parsed result using Parsio (https://parsio.io). It looks correct to me. You can export the parsed data to Sheets / Excel / CSV / Zapier.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for answer, it looks interesting! If this thing realy get the JSON data from pictures you saved my ass).

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements in image contrast and noise reduction (handwork).
Some effect but not obvious.
Image2word
[image: result]